# Homology (or cohomology) with another Homology group, or Cohomology or Homotopy Groups as coefficients

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

What are some interesting examples for something like $H_{n} (X; H_{m} (X) )$ or $H_{n} (X; H^{m} (X) )$ or $H_{n} (X; \Pi_{m} (X) )$ or likewise with Cohomology, i.e. Homology group with another homology group, or cohomology or homotopy groups of the same object as coefficients? Or are things too trivial or too difficult or not very illuminating?

If $H_{m} (X) = \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ then it reduces to $H_{n} (X; \mathbb{Z})$ or $H_{n} (X; \mathbb{Z}_{2})$ which is not too informative on how such a relation defines the object.
Are there any relations like Poincare or Serre duality? or any exact sequences or some other constructions that are helpful in understanding the object $X$?

Comment: I came across Serre Spectral Sequence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_spectral_sequence), which take Cohomology of a space with coefficients in the Cohomology of the Fiber (here of Fibration). Since fibrations are homotopy equivalence liftings, one is using the local (fiber at a point) cycles in the fiber as "sort of generators" for cycles in the concerned space. And this is conditionally convergent in nice cases to usual Cohomology. Grading structure on Cohomology (Serre grading) has interesting differential maps. The construction (for p+q = n) is often referred to as En page.

Comment: Homotopy Fixed Point Spectral Sequence (taking the Homotopy fixed points on the Whitehead filtration produces the conditionally convergent spectral sequence) and likewise another (similar) one for the Tate construction; are (I think) variants of the Serre Spectral Sequence, that use the Homotopy groups instead. I came across these ideas in a lecture series on Topological Cyclic Homology.